# How can I use Java Stream in Dijkstra in one line

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to implement Dijkstra and am learning streams as well. I am not able to implement the below code snippet using streams. I am trying to use streams to iterate the map, filter the key based on the node, and update the dist array, all in one line.

````
input adj=[[2,1,1],[2,3,1],[3,4,1]] 
n=4
S(Source)=2


class Pair{
    int node;
    int weight;
    public Pair(int weight,int node) {
        this.node=node;
        this.weight=weight;
    }
}
    
class Solution {
    public int dijkstra(int[][] adj, int n, int S) {
    
        int [] dist=new int[n];
        Arrays.fill(dist,(int)1e9);
        Map <Integer,List<Pair>>  dic;
        dic=new HashMap<>();
       
        for(int i=0;i<adj.length;i++) {
               
            int nd=(int)adj[i][1];
            int wt=(int)adj[i][2];
            Pair p=new Pair(wt,nd);
    
            dic.computeIfAbsent((int)adj[i][0],y->new LinkedList<Pair>()).add(p);
        }
            
        PriorityQueue <Pair>pq=new PriorityQueue<>((x,y)->x.weight-y.weight);
        dist[k-1]=0;
        pq.add(new Pair(0,S));
    
        while(pq.size() > 0) {
    
            int dis=pq.peek().weight;
            int node=pq.peek().node;
            pq.remove();
    
    // How to implement the below code using Streams in one line
    ------------------------------------------------
    
            dic.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e->e.getKey().equals(node))
                .filter(entry -> entry.getValue()
                .forEach(p->{
                    if(dis+p.weight<dist[p.node-1]){
                    dist[p.node-1]=dis+p.weight;
                    pq.add(new Pair(dis+p.weight,p.node));
                        }
                }));
            }   
        }
    }

```
````

Comment: Dijkstra invented several standard algorithms. Which one do you mean?